# Unexpected symbol error in R that doesn't match my code

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, unexpected-token

I am coding in R-studio and have a function called `saveResults()`. It takes:

- `sce` - a Single Cell Experiment object.
- `opt` - a list with five things
- `clusterLabels` - simple dataframe with two columns

The important thing is that I receive an error stating:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"saveResults(sce = sce, opt = opt, clusteInputs()
zhengMix"
```

which doesn't agree at all with the parameters I pass into the function. You can see this on the last line of the code block below: I pass in proper parameters, but I receive an error that says I have passed in `clusteInputs()`, and `zhengMix` instead of `clusterLabels`. I don't have a function called `clusteInputs()`, and `zhengMix` was several lines above.

```
# Save the clustering data
InstallAndLoadPackagesForSC3Clustering()
opt <- GetOptionInputs()
zhengMix <- FetchzhengMix(opt)
sce <- CreateSingleCellExperiment(zhengMix)
clusterLabels <- getClusterLabels(sce)
opt <- createNewDirectoriesToSaveData(opt)
saveResults <- function(sce, opt, clusterLabels){
    print("Beginning process of saving results...")
    maxClusters = ncol(clusterLabels)/2+1
    for (n in 2:maxClusters){
        savePCAasPDF(sce, opt, numOfClusters = n, clusterLabels)
        saveClusterLabelsAsRDS(clusterLabels, numOfClusters = n, opt)
    }
    saveSilhouetteScores(sce, opt)
    print("Done.")
}
saveResults(sce = sce, opt = opt, clusterLabels = clusterLabels)
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? I'm pretty stuck on this.

Comment: How are you running this code. Are you copy/pasting into RStudio? Seems like your input has a bad character in there. Have you tried retyping it?

Comment: I call the code in the R file from terminal using the bash command Rscript.

Comment: Well, did you type all those commands in that file or did you copy paste at any point? Sounds like you just have an errant line feed character in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution, but I fixed my own problem by removing the code out of the function and running it there caused no issues.